# How to convert edge-values of a 3d histogram into mid-point values of the histogram?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, histogram, interpolation, histogram2d

If `hist, (x, y, z) = numpy.histogramdd()` gives you the histogram values at positions (*x*, *y*, *z*) corresponding to the *edges* of the bins for a three-dimensional function, how one can calculate (interpolate) the histogram values at *midpoints* namely (*x+d/2*, *y+d/2*, *z+d/2*) where *d* is the fixed size of bins in all three directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `np.histogramdd` gives you the bin boundaries in `x, y, z`, but the counts are "at the midpoints", not the boundaries (strictly speaking they are neither, they are over `d x d x d` cubes centered at the midpoints).

If---for some reason---you have values at boundaries and want to interpolate and if you are ok with linear interpolation:

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(hist, (2, 2, 2, *map((-1).__add__, hist.shape)), 2 * hist.strides).mean(axis=(0, 1, 2))
```

This simply takes the average of the 8 nearest neighbors.